# Append / insert / concat rows to dataframe only if record is not already present

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes of customer information:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'firstname':['jack','john','donald'],
                  'lastname':['ryan','obrien','trump'],
                   'email':['mymail@gmail.com','hismail@gmail.com','email@website.com'],
                   'bank_account':['abcd123','jhkf123','kdlk123']})

print(df1)

  firstname lastname              email bank_account
0      jack     ryan   mymail@gmail.com      abcd123
1      john   obrien  hismail@gmail.com      jhkf123
2    donald    trump  email@website.com      kdlk123


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'firstname':['jack','patrick','barak'],
                  'lastname':['ryan','murphy','obama'],
                   'email':['mymail@gmail.com','some@email.com','other@email.com'],
                   'bank_account':[pd.np.nan]*3})

print(df2)


  firstname lastname             email  bank_account
0      jack     ryan  mymail@gmail.com           NaN
1   patrick   murphy    some@email.com           NaN
2     barak    obama   other@email.com           NaN
```

I want to insert the records from `df2` into `df1` but only if they are **not** present in `df1`.

For example we can see that `jack ryan` is present in `df2` and `df1`, so i don't want him to be inserted into the `df1`.

The `primary key` in this situation can be the email. If the email exists in `df1`, do not insert the record.

I've been experimenting and googling with `pd.concat` for the last while, setting `email` as the index etc. and can't get the result I want, which is this:

```
  firstname lastname              email  mobile       address bank_account
0      jack     ryan   mymail@gmail.com   12346   main street      abcd123
1      john   obrien  hismail@gmail.com   51234   high street      jhkf123
2    donald    trump  email@website.com   54856   white house      kdlk123
3   patrick   murphy     some@email.com    6548  north street          NaN
4    barack    obama    other@email.com    2135       florida          NaN
```

You can see in the expected output that `jack ryan` has not been appended to the new dataframe, as the `email` was checked before appending the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to **[`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)** and then use **[`drop-duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)**

```
pd.concat([df1,df2], ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates('email')
```

Output:

```
      firstname lastname              email  mobile       address bank_account
0      jack     ryan   mymail@gmail.com   12346   main street      abcd123
1      john   obrien  hismail@gmail.com   51234   high street      jhkf123
2    donald    trump  email@website.com   54856   white house      kdlk123
3   patrick   murphy     some@email.com    6548  north street          NaN
4    barack    obama    other@email.com    2135       florida          NaN
```

Comment: Ok thank you. If you notice in `df1` there are bank accounts. These cannot be deleted / dropped. If there is a duplicate detected, is it possible that the record with the `bank_account` would be deleted instead of the other one? I really want to avoid this 100% of the time. I cannot risk deleting the record with the bank account.

Comment: This does just that. As you can see `df1` comes first and all the records of `df1` will be put before `df2`. In `drop_duplicates` by default `keep='first'`, which means, `df2` duplicates would be dropped. @SCool

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```py
df1_unique = df1['email'].unique()
df1 = df1.append(df2.loc[~df2['email'].isin(df1_unique), :])
df1
```

Output:

```py
    firstname   lastname    email               bank_account
0   jack        ryan        mymail@gmail.com    abcd123
1   john        obrien      hismail@gmail.com   jhkf123
2   donald      trump       email@website.com   kdlk123
1   patrick     murphy      some@email.com      NaN
2   barak       obama       other@email.com     NaN
```